# Excel vba code for adding a value to existing cell of sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

I have this code to add value of a cell to an existing value of the other cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("E3")) Is Nothing) Then
        Range("F3").Value = Range("E3").Value + Range("F3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

But my problem is it just work in one cell, but not in a row, that is e. g. I want to add up `B1` value to `A1` existing value. It works OK, but i have 24 rows, that is `B2` to `A2` it don't work I don't want to add them combine but separably `B2` to `A2` and `B3` to `A3` this way 24 times.

Please help, it's urgent.

Comment: What? All this does is add E3 to F3 if your changed E3? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be vba?

If you select column B copy (ctrl+c) then select column A and goto paste special you can use the add operator to do what you want.

Otherwise this function would work everytime you change a cell in column B it would update column A as column A+column B (for the specific row).

Gordon

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim int_range As Range

Set int_range = Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
If Not (int_range Is Nothing) Then
    For Each c In int_range
        c.Offset(0, -1).Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value + c.Value
    Next
End If
End Sub
```